# Try Multiple Ports in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am writing an ansible playbook to provision a web server for me. Part of this process involves using the geerlingguy/ansible-role-security role (which I use to change the default ssh port). However, since the port changes, you cannot run the playbook over and over without changing the ansible_ssh_port variable. This seems to go against the whole point of idempotence, since you have to edit the playbook between runs. So I was wondering if there was a way to describe 2 ports for ansible to try. That way it would use port 22 the first time the script runs, but all other times it would use the other port.

I tried searching for ways to try different ports, but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar scenario and found an workaround using [wait_for](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/wait_for_module.html) and [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) modules.

The idea is to set `ansible_port` if a port is accessible. 
Below is a sample that checks and sets a port specified using `port1` variable. It's not necessary to use `ignore_errors` or check the result in this sample scenario but could be useful if multiple ports needed to be tested. Also, `delegate_to: localhost` may be used if a play is using a remote host.

Extend the implementation further using loops, block, rescue etc. as appropriate.

```yaml
- name: test1
  wait_for:
    host: hostname
    port: "{{ port1 }}"
    timeout: 10
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: result
  delegate_to: localhost

- name: set ansible_port
  set_fact:
    ansible_port: "{{ port1 }}"
  when: not result.failed
```

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue when it got failed in the gather fact step so I

Disabled gather facts in my playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    refused: "port 22: Connection refused"
```

Added the tasks that checks the connection (default port is 22)

```yaml
  - name: Check ssh port
    command: /bin/true
    ignore_unreachable: yes
    register: result
    become: yes

  - name: set ansible_port
    set_fact:
      ansible_port: {{ port }}
    when: result.msg is defined and refused in result.msg
```